# React route component re-renders when the parent component state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In App.js, I am passing state and functions to Header.js, SideDrawer.js, Footer.js as props. Every time the state of App.js changes (i.e. when I click on the links on Header.js), Home.js re-renders (I am not passing anything to Home.js), is that normal? How do I prevent Home.js from re-rendering?

I have tried changing Home Component (it's a class component) to PureComponent, but it still re-renders when the state of App changes.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sideDrawerOpen: false,
    subMenuOpen: false,
    modalOpen: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }

  sideDrawerOpenHandler = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { sideDrawerOpen: !prevState.sideDrawerOpen };
    });
  };

  sideDrawerCloseHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      sideDrawerOpen: false
    });
  };

  subMenuOpenHandler = () => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        return { subMenuOpen: !prevState.subMenuOpen };
      },
      () => {
        document.addEventListener("click", this.subMenuCloseHandler);
      }
    );
  };

  subMenuCloseHandler = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        subMenuOpen: false
      },
      () => {
        document.removeEventListener("click", this.subMenuCloseHandler);
      }
    );
  };

  modalOpenHandler = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { modalOpen: !prevState.modalOpen };
    });
  };
  modalCloseHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    let backDrop;

    if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen || this.state.modalOpen) {
      backDrop = (
        <Backdrop
          sideDrawerCloseHandler={this.sideDrawerCloseHandler}
          subMenuCloseHandler={this.subMenuCloseHandler}
          modalCloseHandler={this.modalCloseHandler}
        />
      );
    }

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
          <Router>
            <Header
              sideDrawerOpenHandler={this.sideDrawerOpenHandler}
              subMenuOpenHandler={this.subMenuOpenHandler}
              subMenuOpen={this.state.subMenuOpen}
              // subMenuCloseHandler={this.subMenuCloseHandler}
            />
            <Alerts />
            {this.state.modalOpen && (
              <Trivia modalCloseHandler={this.modalCloseHandler} />
            )}
            <SideDrawer
              sideDrawerOpen={this.state.sideDrawerOpen}
              sideDrawerCloseHandler={this.sideDrawerCloseHandler}
              subMenuOpenHandler={this.subMenuOpenHandler}
              subMenuOpen={this.state.subMenuOpen}
              subMenuCloseHandler={this.subMenuCloseHandler}
            />
            {backDrop}
            <Footer
              modalOpenHandler={this.modalOpenHandler}
              subMenuCloseHandler={this.subMenuCloseHandler}
            />
            <main>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/roster/lakers" component={Lakers} />
                <Route path="/roster/celtics" component={Celtics} />
                <Route path="/roster/rockets" component={Rockets} />
                <Route path="/roster/raptors" component={Raptors} />
                <Route path="/roster/clippers" component={Clippers} />
                <Route path="/roster/bucks" component={Bucks} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
              </Switch>
            </main>
          </Router>
        </AlertProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is because you are changing the state of the App, so it will re-invoke the `render` function. btw, you can still stop that by defining the Home component as `PureComponent` and implement the `componentShouldUpdate` or you can use `React.memo`

Comment: I have tried changing Home Component to PureComponent, but it still re-renders when the state of App changes.

Comment: you still need to implement the `componentShouldUpdate`

Comment: I thought by defining PureComponent, it automatically handles ShouldComponentUpdate for you? Correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a parent view re-renders, so do all it's visible children. You can wrap your home component in a [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) if it's a functional component, or use the [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle method if it's a class. This should prevent unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add that Home is a class component, and I have tried changing Home to PureComponent, but it still re-renders...

Comment: The only thing that differentiates PureComponent from a regular Component is it does a shallow comparison of props and state and decides whether to update or not. If you'd like to not re-render Home component at all, try returning false from shouldComponentUpdate.